# Array not storing entire string (seemingly)

Tags: php, php-7

Why is the following code failing to store the entire strings from the "name" column into my output array?  The code did work at some point.

```
$contacts = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM s_issue.t_contact WHERE orgid='$orgid' ORDER BY id";
$results = db_query($db, $sql, "psql");
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($results)){
    $contacts[$row["id"]] = $row["name"];
}

return $contacts;
```

The database column `id` contains integers, and the `name` column contains strings.  The expected output was a list of contact names, but in my initial trials, I was getting a blank list.

I was asked to look at some very old legacy code.  It was non-obvious as to the recency of the upgrade to PHP7, and when I started looking I wasn't even sure it was PHP7.

Comment: If you are going to answer your own question, please post a complete question.  What are the database column values?  What is the actual output and what is the expected output.  Set it all up and spell it all out please.  Did you just upgrade to `php7`? If so, then this question would benefit from wearing a `php7` tag.

Comment: I did try to tag it with PHP7 but the tag was not offered.  I see there does exists several versions now that I've made a more determined search, and have added it.  I've also revised the question description.

Answer (score 2):

In case you come across some legacy code like this, and find yourself wondering why the output array does not contain what you expect, have you recently upgraded to PHP7?  Because that's the cause.

The initial line in PHP7 now *coercively* (default) types `$contacts` as a string.  Further, a string can be indexed numerically to access each character in that string.  That is:

```
$foo = "abcde";
echo $foo[1]; // outputs 'b'
```

So when `$row["id"]` is numeric, then `$contacts[$row["id"]]` becomes a string with a numeric index.  Hence, only one character can be stored at that location, and it is the first character of the string `$row["name"]`.

The proper fix is to either remove the wrongly-typed initialization line of `$contacts = ""` completely, or correctly initialize it to the type actually desired, an array:

```
$contacts = array();
```

The code in question worked fine before PHP7.  It will fail in mysterious ways in PHP7.